# Why doesn't Lily have the scar?

Tags: harry-potter

According to what I believe is correct, Lily Potter should be the Horcrux, not Harry. When You-Know-Who got to the Potter house, he killed James Potter first. James was trying to protect Lilly and Harry. So, when You-Know-Who killed Lily, it SHOULD have turned back on him because of James' love! That would leave Lily with the scar. So, why didn't she live? (I created an alternate story with this as the logic. So, in my story, James dies, Lily and Harry live. Then, Lily marries Snape, who abuses Harry and Harry grows up with depression, which causes him to have a lack of friends, and he never does anything great, which includes stopping You-Know-Who in his first year. He's back, and he kills Harry, his target in the first place. This gives Lily depression, and she lives an unhappy life while Snape tries to help her through her problems. I kind of see now why it's best that Harry's parents die. But tell me why it didn't happen like this.)

Comment: [Why didn't James' love and sacrifice for Lily protect her?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/why-didnt-james-love-and-sacrifice-for-lily-protect-her?rq=1)

Comment: Snape loved Harry as he loved Lily and Harry had Lily's eyes. All through the series, everything Snape did was to protect Harry and he was always on their side. He would also stand against Dumbledore in doing so. So I don't believe that Snape would abuse Harry. Also, Voldemort wouldn't kill Harry, he would rather kill Lily as she would have been the one who survived his curse in your story. The series would be a Lily Potter series and Harry would just be a simple kid of a famous personality.

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate, since this is asking about the creation of a a horcrux, not the protective sacrifice that blocks Avada Kedavra. The word horcrux doesn't appear **even once** on the other question that supposedly answers this one.